# Why does my device keep disappearing from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a motorola moto G play connected by USB cable to my macbook pro, which is running android studio 3.5.1

Android Studio picks up the device, initially calling it 'Unknown Device', then correctly identifying it as a moto G play, and then the device disappears from the list of available devices. It cycles round doing this every few seconds, making it impossible to install anything.

Any ideas? Could it be the cable?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's rather odd. Does the USB cable work fine with the phone for other things like charging and regular data transfer?

Comment: Perhaps trying with another cable would be the thing to do?

Comment: @Sharvin Ah you are a genius! You set me on an investigative path where I found out that I need to drag down the notification bar in the phone and switch the status from 'USB for charging' to 'USB for file transfer'. Then it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Bruce Sure, glad it somehow helped :)

Comment: just leaving this here for future visitors. My new Pixel 6 did not work with a cable I use for all other phones, but needed the one that was included in the box. (USB-C to USB-C)